Rotations of coordinate for differently scaled x and y axes
I have a primitive coordinate system where x and y axis are the basis vectors that are orthogonal. Now the lattice constant along x and y is differnt let us say $a_x$ and $a_y$.
I have a vector $\vec{v} = r a_x \hat{x} + q a_y \hat{y}$ in this coordinate basis, where $\hat{x} = \vec{x}/|x|$. Now I want to rotate the coordinate to in the direction of $v_{||}$ and $v_{\perp}$. This is by far a very simple high school stuff I know. We follow the usual scheme:
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta  & \sin \theta  \\
-\sin \theta  & \cos \theta 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1/a_x & 0 \\
0 & 1/a_y 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
where we are rescaling the coordinates as $\overline{x} = x/a_x$ and $\overline{y} = y/a_y$ (on the right hand side). But they will be not orthogonal since $a_x \ne a_y$.
Is there a way to restore orthogonality? So that I can work in the rotated coordinate system while mainting the orthogonality?
I know it is a very trivial question.
Let us consider if I have a periodic boundary condition along $y-$axis.
Important question:
Can I have a meaningful Fourier transform along this axis $y'$ that is not even orthogonal to $x'$?

Any linearly independent set of vectors which span a space can be made into an orthogonal basis of that same space via the Gram–Schmidt process.

Thanks, Albertus! I also added a main part to the question that is missing before.
